# How can i change the property 'description' in a popup?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I really need help with this guys. Im using MapBox gl in my html with some markers and popups. I need to change the description property in my script with other information.

I have information 1 - click the button - show information 2

I don't know how to call the property 'description' to change the text in it.

```
map.addLayer({
        "id": "places",
        "type": "circle",
        "paint":{
            "circle-color": "#E00819",
            "circle-radius": 6
        },
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "description": "<p id='texto1'><strong>País:</strong> Colombia<br><strong>Ciudad:</strong> Bogotá<br><strong>Representante:</strong> Diana Carolina Rey<br><strong>Contacto:</strong> Tel: [int. +57 1] 320 1511<br><strong>Email:</strong> contactenos@fundalectura.org.co<br><strong>Web:</strong> <a href=\"http://fundalectura.org/\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Opens in a new window\">www.fundalectura.org</a></p>"


                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [-74.08083, 4.59889 ]
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What are you trying to implement? Showing the description in a popup when you click on the circle?

Comment: @AnatolySukhanov Yes! but when i click a button i need to change the information in it